# Tensors Understanding

Tags: special-relativity, lorentz-symmetry

Yesterday , I spent the whole day searching for articles on Lorentz transformations and found many .

I read the one in Wikipedia and also a school library book. However I couldn't get Tensors.It seemed that suddenly an unrelated topic cropped up . I also couldn't find related things on the Tensors page of Wikipedia.It has too much high level maths that is difficult for me to understand .

Please explain tensors to me and their relation with Lorentz Transformations.

Comment: This is question contains nothing that cannot be looked up on a standard textbook though.

Comment: I currently don't have any such book.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it shows [insufficient prior research](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/5778/what-counts-as-sufficient-prior-research-when-asking-a-question).

Comment: Then look at least on Wikipedia? You can come back when you have a concrete question, but I don't think anyone will give you a complete introduction to such a broad topic here, when it can already be looked up in so many places...

Comment: -1. If you edit your question with your research efforts then I'll come back with +1.

Comment: @Frobenius I have edited it

Comment: OK. I return with +1.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Consider you are in a train travelling at speed $V$, and you're walking at speed $v$. Then, it seems intuitive that your speed in relation to the ground will be $V + v$: this is Galileo's transformation, and it's false.

Indeed, it is quite accurate in everyday life, *ie.* when speeds aren't to high. However, when the speed of the train will become not small in comparison with the speed of light, Galileo's transformation will be totally false: in fact, according to it, your speed in relation to the ground could be greater than the speed of light, and this is impossible. So, we have to use another transformation, which would be almost Galileo's one for small speeds, and would respect the speed limit of the speed of light: this is Lorentz transformation.

Speed is affected by Lorentz transformation, so also position, and acceleration. But, since light is travelling at the same speed in the train and for an observer on the ground (this is a postulate of special relativity, which is totally counter-intuitive, but experimentally true), time must be affected as well.

So, Lorentz transformation is the transformation that allow you to know what are the position and the time in a frame of reference when you know them in another frame of reference. Their mathematical expression aren't really interesting, but you can find them [on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_transformation) (you can quickly check that Galileo and Lorentz transformation predict the same results for small speeds).

Lorentz transformation is the very first tool used to study special relativity kinematics, so its applications are the one of special relativity, for example GPS, cathode-ray tube monitors, relativist Doppler-Fizeau effet, *etc.*